# Is there a way to open an Outlook Desktop Alert with the keyboard?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, autohotkey

I'm wondering if there is a way to open an Outlook Desktop Alert with the keyboard.

If not I will probably create a handler via an AutoHotKey script, could there be a better solution?

Comment: Have you looked at this?  http://www.howto-outlook.com/howto/newmailalert.htm

Comment: Thanks, setting the display time allowed me to find the solution. You can <alt><tab> to it and press enter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Tab</kbd> to the alert, the hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open it.

It might be useful to increase the display time from 3 seconds.

This can be done via the registry key (in ms):

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\DesktopAlerts\TimeOn

To keep it open indefinitely, set the max hex value: fffff448.